# Selenium + webdriver-manager -> selenium error status code -9

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

The project uses `Selenium` and `geckodriver`. The geckodriver and the path to it comes from the package webdriver-manager package (https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/). This saves the geckodriver executable at path `/Users/myusername/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0/geckodriver` (i.e. outside the project folder). When I try to run my main.py I get this error:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current firefox version is 96.0
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 96.0 firefox
Driver [/Users/myusername/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0/geckodriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/main.py", line 1184, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/main.py", line 1172, in main
    app = MainApp(root)
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/main.py", line 799, in __init__
    driver = Driver(parent).get_webdriver_object() #instantiate Driver object and return the webdriver object
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/lib/driver.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service_path, options=self.opts)
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/Users/myusername/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/myusername/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

I have used webdriver-manager before without problem. It all started I think when I upgraded my python (and wanted to use venv).

This is the code:

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import settings
import tkinter as tk


class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        driver = Driver(parent).get_webdriver_object() #instantiate Driver object and return the webdriver object
        self.driver = driver


class Driver():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.executable_path = GeckoDriverManager().install()
            
        self.service_path = Service(self.executable_path)
        self.opts = FirefoxOptions()
        
        #instantiate the driver 
        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service_path, options=self.opts)
    def get_webdriver_object(self):
        return self.driver

        #open url
        self.driver.get(settings.url)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The path to the geckodriver is correct in both code and the computer.
`/Users/username/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0/geckodriver`

I have tried to install the packages on different python environments (with diffrent python versions and inside venv). No luck. Don't know why this started to happen suddenly?

I have tried giving the geckodrivare binary permissions on my Mac (even though I don't get any permissions error):

```
One simple workaround works right from the Finder:

control-click on the geckodriver binary but keep the mouse button/touch pad pressed...
remove finger from control key and press on option key...
you will see the menu change...
then select the "open" menu item with the mouse/touchpad and it will open in the terminal.
close the terminal and you are done. You have given macOS permission to run that binary.
Note: this works for all binaries Catalina rejects so this works for chromedriver for Chrome as well
```

Comment: Could you show the code you wrote?

Comment: @AnandGautam I added the code

Comment: Have you installed `WebdriverManager` in the venv? If not, you have to. When the code is executed, a driver instance would be created in the venv and that would be used for the scripts

Comment: @AnandGautam Yes. I have installed the Webdriver-manager package in the venv. `/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/App3.0/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webdriver_manager`. The webdriver-manager creates the path correctly as I can print the correct path to the geckodriver on my computer.